# Clear stdout in Python CGI after os.system

Tags: python, apache, svg, cgi

I'm using os.system to call an external program (Apache Batik) that converts svg data to an image. Then I would like to download the image in the user's disk.

But whenever I call the cgi with Apache, I get the error :

```
 malformed header from script. Bad header=About to transcode 1 SVG file
```

That is the stdout from the os.system command, so after searching I found that I could use `sys.stdout.flush()` to resolve the problem but unfortunately it still gives the same error. Here's the script :

```
import os
import cgi
import sys
arg = cgi.FieldStorage()
os.system('java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar "batik-1.7/batik-rasterizer.jar" "pythonchart.svg"')
sys.stdout.flush() //NOT WORKING, STILL THE SAME ERROR

print "Content-Type: image/png"
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pythonchart.png"
print
print open("pythonchart.png","rb").read()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE
from time import sleep

x = Popen('external-command -test paramater', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
while x.poll() == None:
    sleep(0.025)
x.stdout.close()
x.stdin.close()
```

Consider using `Popen` instead.
One clear benefit is that you can control the stdout/stdin in a much neater way which doesn't "bleed" out into your main program. Secondly you could potentially send inputs to your external application if need be.

Comment: Now I wonder why is there such a leak!? The `system()` function in C doesn't do that at all. It would be pretty terrible if it did, actually.